# Delete all channels in a specific category

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How to delete all channels in a specific category in Discord.JS?
I tried that

```
oldMember.guild.channels.cache.get(client.tr["Settings"].MainChannelID).parent.channels.cache.forEach(c => {
        if(c.members.size != 0){
            c.delete();
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the channels that belong to a category using [`CategoryChannel.children`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CategoryChannel?scrollTo=children)

```js
const category = await oldMember.guild.channels.cache.get(CATEGORY_ID); // You can use `find` instead of `get` to fetch the category using a name: `find(cat => cat.name === 'test')
category.children.forEach(channel => channel.delete())
```

Answer (score 0):

### how about using a search for the category you define?

1. I added a search by category name, so just use the command and type the category name
2. I recommend adding a command that only administrators can use. for example `if (!message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply("You need permission 'ADMINISTRATOR'")`

```
 if (!message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply("You need permission `ADMINISTRATOR`")

let category = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name == args.join(" ") && c.type == "category")
 category.children.forEach(channel => channel.delete())
```