# Deleting every channel in a specified category in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to delete every channel in a specified category in discord.py.

My code so far:

```
category = client.get_channel(my_id_here)
```

I was thinking of iterating through each of the channels in that category however I'm not sure how to go about doing so.

I saw [a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61826256/delete-all-channels-in-a-specific-category) on this however that's in discord.js so I would need the discord.py equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out the solution, hope it helps someone:

```
category = client.get_channel(id_here)

for channel in category.voice_channels:
    await channel.delete()
```

If you want to remove text channels, replace `voice_channels` with `text_channels`